# Is the speed of an orbiting object at a given distance enough to uniquely classify an orbit's eccentricity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

[image]

As in the title, I am having trouble with part ii and iii of the linked image. So far i have found the semi-major axis and the period of the orbit both using the vis-viva equation along with proving that it is elliptic.

I have found the eccentricity in terms of the semi major axis and the perihelion and aphelion but I cannot make further progress.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem#Solution_of_the_Kepler_problem
Also, there's missing information about velocity (you've been given only the amplitude)

Comment: Does the fact that the question only give the speed and not the direction mean that the eccentricity is not uniquely determined? Could I find a range of possible eccentricities by considering two extreme cases: e.g. The velocity is parallel to its displacement from the sun and its velocity is perpendicular to its displacement?

Comment: While you would indeed need both a position and velocity vector to fully describe the orbital state, the problem doesn’t ask for the full orbital state; e should be calculable from magnitudes alone.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct: you need to know the distance and velocity (velocity = speed and direction) in order to calculate the eccentricity.  The speed is minimum at aphelion and maximum at perihelion.  There are an infinite number of possible orbits that have a given distance and speed.  If you want to calculate the range of possible eccentricities, let the direction vary between straight toward the Sun, to perpendicular to the sun-satellite line, to straight away from the sun.